# assign color based on date as graph is updated with definition

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am attempting to update a graph with several squiggles derived from a for loop that operates by opening files, skipping rows, and then plot the data in this case depths vs delta O. Each 'squiggle' has a date attached to it in the pandas dataframe. I would like to assign increasingly darker colors of red for younger and younger squiggles that I plot on my graph.

Here is my code:

```
def delO_plot(filename):

        # make a dataframe
        f=open(filename)
        lines=f.readlines()
        f.close()  
        counter=0 
        for line in lines: 
        l=line.strip().split()
        if l[0]=='~A':
            counter
            break
        else:
            counter = counter + 1
    line = lines[counter].strip().split()
    names = line[1:]
    APInum = lines[20].strip().split()  
    df = pd.read_table(filename, skiprows = counter+1, names=names, sep = '\s+')   
    df[df < -990.00] = None
    #for dfs in df:
    plt.plot(df.DEPTH, df.DELO)


# grab all well files in folder
files=glob.glob('*.las')

# well IDs for the ones we want
wells=np.array(df6.wellID)

# these loops find if the wellID is in the filename and if so, runs the           plotting function 
try:
    for g in files:
        for gg in wells:
            if gg in g:
                delO_plot(g)
except AttributeError:
    print g
plt.show()
```

Any and all help would be appreciate as I'm still pretty new to python and data visualization outside of excel.

Comment: Just pass a `color` kwarg to the `plot` call based on mapping the date -> rgb via any function you want.

Comment: Thank you tacaswell could you expand a little more on how to call based on the date with rgb as any function I want?

Comment: I got it to work using:    'mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=['r','b','g'])'   but I would like to use a color map or something. I would like it to use the cm.Blues, where each updated line is a slightly lighter color.....Anyone know of a quick way for this?